# reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts.TTFError: Can't open file "Times New Roman.ttf"

Tags: python, fonts, reportlab

I have problem in importing font times new roman in `ReportLab` python

```
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('TNR', 'Times New Roman.ttf'))
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('TNRB', 'Times New Roman Bold.ttf'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a wrong `filename`.

```
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('TNR', 'times.ttf'))
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('TNRB', 'timesbd.ttf'))
```